# How can I undo changes made to a picture I accidentally saved via preview?

Tags: macos, preview, image-editing, versions

The was a picture that I was looking at in my computer, I drew a line with the preview tool.

Since my was slow and the app was not responsive,  I force quited Preview.

I opened the document and  it saved the line I drew on the picture as part of the picture. I don't have the original picture but I don't want the line to be there.

Can I undo what I have done via a backup or version of this file?

Answer (score 15):

With **Preview** open:

**File > Revert To > Browse All Versions**

Select the original version.

Comment: @LeonelCabreraHerrera If that answer solved the problem, please indicate it by accepting the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Click command z

(you can also click on the edit icon on your screen and click undo)

Comment: Does Undo work if the file got closed and reopened as described in the question?